# Software workaround for a problematic motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, hardware-detection

I have a Gigabyte Z390 Aoros Pro (non-WiFi) which I strongly suspect has a broken RGB controller.

RGB Fusion 2.0 cannot control the RGB, yet it recognises the board.

Every 10mins, on the dot, a random USB device (which I suspect is the RGB controller/interface) disconnects and then reconnects. It's annoying for two reasons - it makes a sound and it flashes up when I am in something full screen.

I am wanting to try everything possible software-based before I completely disassemle my PC and RMA the motherboard.

The device is ALWAYS located at Port#0012.Hub#0001 - I'm wanting to know if there is anyway to permently stop this device from interfacing with Windows, maybe via a registry hack in CurrentControlSet?

I've already tried disabling and uninstalling it in Device Manager, but this doesn't work. When the device reconnects, Windows just tries to reinstall it and any drivers. I've also done a clean Windows install.

I'm at a loss with how to fix this, if it's even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Look for it in device manger, if you find it disable it.

Comment: Have you tried Disable without uninstall? pretty sure it's the uninstall that's making Windows look again, be surprised it has a new toy… & reloading the drivers for it & re-enabling.

Comment: It's the built in motherboard RGB. No cables that I am aware of. Disabling the device didn't work either :/

Answer (score 1):

Try Disconnecting the wire(s) from the rgb controller port(s) on the motherboard. Do this one at a time and see if solves the problem. # 8,9,10.

[image]

Comment: I should clarify that these are the RGB lights built in to the motherboard - not sure if this suggestion still applies?